# Jest integration Tests break on Pipeline

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, integration-testing, bitbucket-pipelines

Hello im trying to find to build a application on my pipeline using integrations tests with Jest version 27.5.1 as well as jest-cli 27.5.1   all the tests work on my localhost however when my code runs through the Pipeline it shows the following Error

```
FetchError: request to http://localhost/callback?usid=  failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
```

and if i add a skip to this test the next test breaks as well

I've tried reading the documentation  of jest to see if the root of the problem could be syntax i changed the Url where im doing the request for the API and also  cleared added  on the function  afterEach() server.resetHandlers() as well as LocalStorage.clear()  to clear up anything that might be considered Old data

Comment: What is being served in `http://localhost/callback` in your localhost? You should also start that service in your CI system if you pretend to run integration tests.

Comment: Please post your `jest.config.js` and `jest.setup.js` (what you specify in `setupFilesAfterEnv` in jest config, where you call `server.listen()`). The error above means you haven't enabled MSW correctly, and your test performs the original request to localhost.

Comment: I managed to solve the issue by dividing the tests in describes the main issue was that the API couldn't reply in time because of the amount of request being made in a short period of time